# onclick Push a string value into a MVC 5 c# Form field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 5 C# 
I am trying to create a site to design a bike and I have the frame, saddle etc changing colour and displaying layered images when the users selects a coloured button.

I want the parameters which are captured with onclick function to then the populate form fields so that I can create a new record in a database.

I got a value to replace the input field on the form with the value but on create it doesn't hit the db.

```
function setFrame(framechoice) {
    var frame = document.getElementById("FrameImage");
    var frameC = document.getElementById("FC");

    if (framechoice === 'Black') {
        framecolor = '<img src="/Content/Images/BlackFrame.png" class="img-responsive">'
    }
    else if (framechoice === 'Red') {
             framecolor = '<img src="/Content/Images/RedFrame.png" class="img-responsive">'
         }
         else if (framechoice === 'Green') {
                  framecolor = '<img src="/Content/Images/GreenFrame.png" class="img-responsive">'
              };

    frame.innerHTML = framecolor;
    frameC.innerHTML = framechoice;
    gframe = framechoice;
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model DesignUrFixie.Models.Bike

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Choose the colours for your components</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div id="FrameColor">
<p><b>FRAME</b> Colour</p>
<p>
    <input type='button' class="button BF"     onclick="setFrame('Black')">
    <input type='button' class="button RF" onclick="setFrame('Red')">
    <input type='button' class="button GF" onclick="setFrame('Green')">
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="SaddleColor">
    <p><b>SADDLE</b> Colour</p>
    <p>
    <input type='button' class="button BF" onclick="setSaddle('Black')">
    <input type='button' class="button RF" onclick="setSaddle('Red')">
    <input type='button' class="button GF" onclick="setSaddle('Green')">
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
</div>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-8">
<div id="GreyBike">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/GreyBike.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div>
    <div id="FrameImage">
    </div>
    <div id="SaddleImage">
    </div>
    <div id="HandlebarImage">
    </div>
    <div id="WheelsImage">
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is where I am finding it hard to try and get the string value from the onclick functions into the form field for FrameColour

I tried placing the id="FC" on the input field and got the text to replace the input field but not go inside it, I hope I am explaining myself clearly...

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Bike</h4>
            <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FrameColour, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
            <div class="col-md-6" id="FC">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FrameColour, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FrameColour, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<input>` your creating with `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FrameColour, ...)` has `id="FrameColour"` (not `id="FC"`) and you want `document.getElementById("FrameColour").value= framechoice;`

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I got it working.
Regards Phil